# ChromeDriver. Switching tabs in headless mode results in page cropping

Tags: java, selenium, tabs, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have a set up, which should use the chromedriver in headless mode:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "tools\\chromedriver.exe");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false");
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
```

Which works fine for **single browser tab** or **single switching between tabs**.
However, when tabs are being switched back and forth, first page is cropped on the right side and part of the page becomes unreachable.

Since this issue can be reproduced only **in headless mode** - I have no idea what could cause it

Can anyone please tell, are there any issues with using chromedriver headless mode with multiple browser tabs?

What I've tried (and it didn't help):

1. Upgrading chromedriver to latest version;
2. Upgrading Chrome
3. Upgrading Jenkins which runs mentioned tests;
4. Adding code that forcibly resizes and moves the window after each tab switching

Comment: Can you past the error message.

Comment: @SneekyTheBreeky Which version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: @Girish > Can you past the error message
https://codeshare.io/5zmWWk

Comment: @DebanjanB > Which version of Selenium are you using?
84.0.4147.30

Comment: @Girish in case link to codeshare expires
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xC0ytfVs-k_-xCuDU_OQ7g96blX3fvx5vZWrMtwC6iw/edit?usp=sharing)